# Working with ROS and Robot Arms

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am  working for my Bachelor Degree with ROS and I have to setup and implement a Robot System.

The final goal is to grab a mug while the robot is driving next to it.

Now my question is, since I am not so good with ros right now and I am at the beginning, what packages there exist to use Robot-Arms and which Robot-Arms are supported?

Is it possible to solve this Problem with ros?

It would be nice if anybody could answer me these questions :) greez

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207124/working-with-ros-and-robot-arms/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a piece of software, [MoveIt!](http://moveit.ros.org/), that is for manipulation motion planning and execution.

What are the specs of your arm? MoveIt supports 6DOF arms very well. However, for lower DOF arms one has to tweak the system a little bit, and do things like generate your own inverse kinematics solvers. There is a little bit of a learning curve.

I'm currently working on integrating a simple 2DOF arm with it, not without challenges, but once you have it setup it can be very powerful.

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-05-10**:
@aak2166  Sir How you integrate your arm with Moveit ? is it based on Arduino ??